# Image Cropper Issue

Tags: java, android

So Im using the ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper. Im having an issue on getting the cropper to popup. So right now Ive got a screen where I click a button and it takes me to my gallery and that is working perfectly fine. I can go to my gallery and all that. But when I click the image from the gallery, instead of it taking me to the crop editor, I go right back to the activity I was just at. This is my code

```
public class TestShareActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageButton imageButton;
private EditText mCaption;
private Button mShareBtn;
private static final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_share);

    imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.profileImageButton);
    mCaption = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addCaption);
    mShareBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadBtn);

    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
            galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST && requestCode == RESULT_OK){


        CropImage.activity()
                .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                .start(this);

    }
}
}
```

I also have both of these in my Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Logcat from when I click the image button to go to my gallery to when I click the image I want which then takes me back to my activity

```
Suspending all threads took: 16.868ms
Recording user engagement, ms: 2309
Activity paused, time: 11770529
Logging event (FE): _e, Bundle[{_o=auto, _et=2309, _sc=TestShareActivity, _si=3274131924141379636}]
showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
Using measurement service
Connecting to remote service
Activity resumed, time: 11775975
Connected to remote service
Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@39c720c9 time:5790129
Processing queued up service tasks: 1
Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Comment: Can you post the logcat content?

Comment: @Aenadon jusst added it. Doesnt really say much I think though.